# React shows a stale state in the render

Tags: reactjs

I have an Image class which allows me to change images from the containiner Component and update the image style.

My Class:

```
import React from "react";
import Radium from 'radium';

class StateImage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            images: this.props.images.map(image => ({
                ...image,
                loaded: false,
                activeStyle: {visibility: 'hidden'}
            })),
            activeMode: props.activeMode
        };

        this.state.images.forEach((image, index) => {

            const src = image.image;

            const primaryImage = new Image();
            primaryImage.onload = () => {

                const images = [...this.state.images];
                images[index].loaded = true;

                if (images[index].name === this.state.activeMode) {
                    images[index].activeStyle = images[index].style;

                    // is this image the default activated one? if so, activate it now that it's loaded.
                    images[index].onActivate();
                } else
                    images[index].activeStyle = {visibility: 'hidden'};

                this.setState( {
                    ...this.state,
                    images
                });
            };
            primaryImage.src = src;

        });
    }



    updateImageStyle = (name, style) => {

        let images = [...this.state.images].map( (image) => {
            if (image.name === name) {
                return {
                    ...image,
                    style: style,
                    activeStyle: style
                }
            }  else return image;
        });

        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            images: images
        }, () => {
            console.log("updated state");
            console.log(this.state);

        });


    };

    onClick = () => {
         this.state.images.map( (image) => {
             if (image.clickable && image.name === this.state.activeMode)
                this.props.eventHandler(this.state.activeMode);
         });

    };

    render () {
        console.log("render");
        console.log(this.state.images);

        let images = this.state.images.map((image, index) => {
             return <img
                 key={ index }
                 onClick={ this.onClick }
                 style={ image.activeStyle }
                 src={ image.image }
                 alt={ image.alt}/>
         });

        return (
            <div>
                {images}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Radium(StateImage);
```

My problem revolves around `updateImageStyle`. When this function is called I need to change the `style` element of the active image and re-render so that users see the change.

`updateImageStyle` is reached, and I update the `images` portion of my `state`. I `console.log` it once the `setState` is done and I can verify the change was made correctly!

However, I also console.log from the `render` and to my amazement, the `this.state.images` outputted from `render` is *stale* and does not reflect my changes.

How can this be? the `console.log` proves the `render` that has the stale state is called AFTER I have confirmed my changes have taken place.

My console log:
[image]

Comment: You are most likely seeing your state being overwritten by a different setState call perhaps the one in `primaryImage.onload` since React batches setState together render() is called only once with the updates.

Comment: hmm! interesting. I'll test that theory.

Comment: You are correct! I `console.log` the `setState` called from the `primaryImage.onLoad` and that is indeed called ***AFTER*** the style update! - Thanks. If you post this as an answer, I'll be able to credit you for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely seeing your state being overwritten by a different setState call perhaps the one in `primaryImage.onload`. Since React batches `setState` calls together, `render()` is called only once with the updates.